# How to drilldown from Column Chart to Stacked Column Chart using High Charts

Tags: highcharts, drilldown, stacked-chart

Can we drilldown from Column Chart to Stacked Column Chart using High Charts ? , Is there any demo / example ?

Comment: what do you mean by "can we drilldown"? Do you mean a way to switch between stacked and non-stacked columns?

Comment: I have a feeling there's more to your question (multiple series?), but this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/frjtcwhs/

Comment: Ondkloss - In Multiple series you have column to column series , i need column to stacked column series.

Comment: ZekeDroid - I mean Multiple series.

Comment: See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/vNfWk/42/